Can Signature Move be played if you have 2 copies in your hand?
The description for the card Signature Move says:

Can only be played if this is the only attack in your hand. Deal 30 damage.

If you have no attacks in your hand other than two copies of Signature Move, will you be able to play it?

That... would be something I would absolutely overlook if I made that game. Haha! That is an excellent question.

If it is a well built game, then you probably will be able to play Signature Move. Well built games most likely have been debugged like crazy, so maybe.

Logicly, if you can't play one of the Signature Moves, you can play the other since the first one can't be played. (I hope that made sense)

@Alex The card can only be played when it is the "only attack in your hand". The question is, does that mean you can only have that type of attack card, or only one attack card total?

Not sure. Sorry I didn't make it clear, but I haven't heard of slay the spire. I just think that the concept is interesting. Someone back me up, please! I want him to get an answer.

So I just tried. (I used console commands to test)

You can not.

Which is consistent with the text of the card. As "this" rather than "Signature Move" is the condition, and in both cases the other Signature move is another Attack in your hand.
